# How to make a form, in a table, for use selection in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I'm building an application where I pass an array from controller to view, fill it in a table and then, the user can select it and make a post. Code bellow.

I don't know how to use form_tag or similar to display and make it available for submiting and let user change the amount. Any help/advice?

Array example

```
[{:stock_id=>10, :name=>"VALE3", :value=>"50.02", :amount=>"5"}, {:stock_id=>10, :name=>"VALE3", :value=>"50.02", :amount=>"5"}]
```

Controller

```
def get_stocks

    if !current_user.nil?
      user = User.all.where(id: current_user&.id)
      @user_stocks = Array.new
      for u in user.first.stocks
        user_stock =  UserStock.find_by(stock_id: u['id'])
        @user_stocks << {stock_id: u['id'],name: u['name'], value: u['value'], amount: user_stock['amount']}
      end
    end
  end
```

View

```
 <div class="table-bordered table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Code</th>
            <th scope="col">Price</th>
            <th scope="col">Amount</th>
            <th scope="col">Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <% @user_stocks.each do |stock| %>
            <%# byebug %>
            <tr>
                <td><%= stock[:name] %></td>
                <td><%= stock[:value] %></td>
                <td><%= stock[:amount] %></td>   ## THE USER NEED TO CHOOSE THE AMOUNT HE/SHE WANTS TO SELL
                <td><%= link_to 'Sell', new_transaction_path %></td>
            </tr>
        <% end %>
    </tbody>
    </table>
 </div>
```

Comment: You need not a one advice here... Why do you write `user = User.all.where(id: current_user&.id)`?! It is just a `current_user`, which you already have

Comment: I think my question was not clear. My doubt here is about presenting the data in the view side. I don't know how to make the field  amount (in <td>) editable by the user.

Comment: Your question is clear. I'm about code quality.

Comment: Thanks though, but I still don't know how to create a choice on the <td> element.

Answer (score 0):

I just started to use Rails so i dont know if this is the best solution but anyways:

You can use the form builder to create a editable text field and something like a save button as shown here:

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#updating-articles

I don't really know if this is the most elegant solution or if you can make it look good with your table, but i hope this helps a bit.

Edit:

to include it in your table you can probably create a _form.html.erb
and create the whole table similar to what iam doing in my task at the moment:

```
    <% @project.order(:title).each do |project| %>
    <tr>
    <td><%= link_to project.title, project_path(project) %></td>
    <td><%= project.status %></td>
    ...
```